# Get a String from json (Vba)

Tags: string, vba

I am very new to Vba and I really hope you can help me. I only got an URL which gives you a text /stream with json syntax.  Now this "json text" should be display in exel. 
So I alreday made it to display a string in exel that I set direktly in my code. But my question is now: how do I get a string from the URL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

if you are behind a proxy server, it could look like this:

```
Const HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY = 2
Dim oRequest As Object 
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.setProxy HTTPREQUEST_PROXYSETTING_PROXY, "http://proxy.intern:8080"
oRequest.Open "GET", "http://www.cboden.de"
oRequest.Send
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

and if you want to use POST instead of GET you can try something like this:

```
Dim oRequest As Object
Set oRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
oRequest.Open "POST", "http://www.cboden.de/misc/posttest.php"
oRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Typ", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oRequest.Send "Formularfeld1=123&Formularfeld2=test"
MsgBox oRequest.ResponseText
```

If you are new to VBA this might be a little bit hard to understand ... but please google the various commands for further informations.

Comment: ok .. then please be so kind and mark the question as answered :-)